# Can one (re)set all the values of an array in one line (after it has been initialized)?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, heap-memory

In C, I know I can make an array like this

```
int myarray[5] = {a,b,c,d,e};
```

However, imagine the array was already initialised like

```
int myarray[5];
```

and then at some point afterwards, I wanted to set/change all the values without going

```
myarray[0] = a;
myarray[1] = b;
myarray[2] = c;
myarray[3] = d;
myarray[4] = e;
```

but rather, something more like

```
myarray = {a,b,c,d,e};
```

The reason why I ask this is because if I declare my array on the heap, I will initialise the array like:

```
int* myarray = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

Then I would like to be able to enter in all the values in one line (mostly to make my code look cleaner)

Comment: So ultimately the answer is "No".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
memcpy(myarray, (int [5]){a,b,c,d,e}, 5*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Yes. But when somebody gives a C++ answer using templates, does it require a comment that requires C++98? Or when I use a function prototype in C, do I need to mention that it won't work in pre-ANSI C implementations? C99 **is** the current C language.

Comment: @R.: Unfortunately many people are stuck with C89, e.g. Microsoft still does not have C99 support in Visual Studio, and many students still have to use antiquated compilers such as Turbo C. So it's probably not justified to assume that the majority of people are able to use C99-specific features.

Comment: From now on I'll always set arrays like this just to be cool and be called genius lol. What a beautiful one liner, I shed a tear.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why is this working, and what says the standards about this kind of construct `(int [5]){a,b,c,d,e}`?

Comment: After a lot of tests i think i got it, i was wondering why u can't do `int *myarray = (int [5]){a,b,c,d,e};`, actually you can, but `myarray` will only be valid inside the function code, outside, if you do `return myarray;` the result will be invalid and thus you must do a `memcpy` into an `malloc` location to use your array outside. If the array is only to be used inside the function, you can shorten your code into: `int *myarray = (int [5]){a,b,c,d,e};`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that is all standards compatible (C89, C99, C++)

It has the advantage that you only worry about entering the data in one place. None of the other code needs to change - there are no magic numbers. Array is declared on the heap. The data table is declared const.

[(Click here to try running it in Codepad)](http://codepad.org/EDeJR9xI)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
unsigned int i = 0;
int *myarray = 0;
static const int  MYDATA[] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};

  myarray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(MYDATA));
  memcpy(myarray, MYDATA, sizeof(MYDATA));

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(MYDATA)/sizeof(*MYDATA); ++i)  
  {
    printf("%i\n", myarray[i]);
  }

  free(myarray);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MYDATA` can also be declared `static`.

Comment: I would vote this up, but only if you change `MYDATA` to `static`. Otherwise most compilers will generate very bad code for it.

Comment: MYDATA will be in .text or .const not .data because it is declared const. It is decalred within function so linkage is internal. Static is therefore not required or helpful. Well in my experience but maybe caf and R have a compiler where it is an issue so to placate them I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

No, C doesn't have such feature. If you are setting all array elements to the same value use [`memset(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memset.3.html).

Comment: This answer can be misleading. `memset` doesn't assign "array elements" to a value. It assigns *bytes* in a memory block to a specific value. The second argument will be interpreted as `char`. For example, you can't use `memset` to initialize elements of an `int[]` to `10`.

Comment: But you can use it to initialize an array of `uint{8,16,32,64}_t` to `UINT{8,16,32,64}_MAX` by passing 255 as the argument. :-)

Comment: R.: no, no, shouldn't use 255 but UCHAR_MAX instead :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *setarray(int *ar,char *str)
{
    int offset,n,i=0;
    while (sscanf(str, " %d%n", &n, &offset)==1)
    {
        ar[i]=n;
        str+=offset;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ar;
}

int main()
{
    int *sz=malloc(5*sizeof(int)),i;

    //call
    setarray(sz,"10 30");

    //output
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        printf("%d\n",sz[i]);

    return 0;
}
```