# set multiple array variables at the same time (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make an ASCII art using C++, and having some problems in arrays.

Is there any way to set multiple array variables at the same time?

Let me be more specific.

When you initialize an array, you can do this way.

```
int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

By the way shown above, you can set 10 array variables at the same time.

However, I want to (re) set some of the array variables like this?

```
a[1] = 3;
a[4] = 2;
a[5] = 2;
a[7] = 2;
```

Since there is **NO** rule in  the variables, I can't do

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) a[i] = i+1;
fill(n);
```

I can't use an **for** statement or the **fill, fill_n** function, since there is no regularity.

To sum up,
Is there any way to set more than 1 array variables at the same time? (Like the second code snipplet above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one (re)set all the values of an array in one line (after it has been initialized)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294333/can-one-reset-all-the-values-of-an-array-in-one-line-after-it-has-been-initia)

Comment: Put the array in a `struct` and assign structures `a = b`.

Comment: flagged as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294333/can-one-reset-all-the-values-of-an-array-in-one-line-after-it-has-been-initia

Comment: @savram no, this question is not *all* variables, just some.  That question is *all*.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same time"?

Comment: "the same time" means in a single line, or much simple than using N lines for settings N variables.

Comment: I'm asking is there any way much simple than that.

Comment: "I can't use an for statement" and OP selects [a `for` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334397/2410359)??

Comment: @chux From OPs question I understood that he can't just simply change all the values sequentially with a `for` - not as a requirement to not use any `for` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a index-value mapping list, and assign it one by one.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void Update(T(&arr)[N], const std::vector<std::pair<size_t, T>>& mappings)
{
    for (const auto& mapping : mappings) 
        if(mapping.first < N)
            arr[mapping.first] = arr[mapping.second];
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Update(arr, { {1, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {7, 2} });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware without a pattern a control structure is kind of redundant, you might be better served reading from a file.

```
// for user input
    int arr[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Please input your value for array index " << i << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // for manual input in initalization
    int arr[10] = { 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

However a better approach might be to read it from a file, http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/58945/ Read "TheMassiveChipmunk"'s post there for exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know which indices you will be changing upfront you can use a separate index array:

```
int ind[4]= {1,4,5,7};
```

..and an accompanying array with values

```
int new_val[4] = {3,2,2,2};
```

The you can use the following `for` loop to assign the values:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    arr[ind[i]] = new_val[i];
```

You should also use some variable signifying the number of indices to be changed like `int val_num = 4` instead of plain number 4.

Answer (score 0):

Changes that are defined in runtime to an array can be easily implemented by using a list to save tuples that represent the changes you want to make. As an example, we can write:

```
 #include <tuple>                                                                
 #include <list>                                                                 
 #include <iostream>                                                             

 using namespace std;                                                            
 typedef tuple <int, int> Change;                                                

 int main() {                                                                    
     int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};                                                     
     list<Change> changes;                                                       

     //represents changing the 2-th entry to 8.                                  
     Change change(2,8);                                                         
     changes.push_back(change);

     for(auto current_change: changes)                                           
         a[get<0>(current_change)] = get<1>(current_change);                                     
     cout << a[2] << '\n';                                                       
 }
```

Prints 8.