# Assigning multiple elements of array in one statement(after initialization)

Tags: c++, arrays, assignment-operator

```cpp
    std::string mstring[5];
        mstring[0] = "veena";
        mstring[1] = "guitar";
        mstring[2] = "sitar";
        mstring[3] = "sarod";
        mstring[4] = "mandolin";
```

I want to assign the array like above. I don't want to do it at initialization but assign later. Is there a way to combine 5 statements into one.

Comment: Dupe: [Can one (re)set all the values of an array in one line (after it has been initialized)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294333/can-one-reset-all-the-values-of-an-array-in-one-line-after-it-has-been-initia)

Comment: Why do you want to declare/define an array before you initialise it?    In the code between the definition (without initialisation) and the subsequent initialisation, the array can't be used anyway without causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Its `mstring[4]`. My bad.

Comment: Why the question was reopened? This is exact dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294333/can-one-reset-all-the-values-of-an-array-in-one-line-after-it-has-been-initia). The only difference is that in the dupe there is no C++ tag which doesn't matter here as built in arrays are one of the things inherited from C. And these questions are very closely related.

Comment: @AnoopRana C++ has no array literals, and the answer there definitely doesn't apply.

Comment: @lorem1213 *I don't want to do it at initialization but assign later.* -- A question -- why aren't you declaring your variables close(r) to where you will actually use them?  What's the reason for declaring the array so far away from it's actual use point?  One advantage that C++ gives you over `C` is that you can declare variables at the point of usage, and not at the top of a `{ }` block.

Comment: To answer the question as asked, no there is not a way.   Raw arrays (as distinct from `std:array` in C++, which has different capabilities) cannot be assigned in a single statement (except by techniques to do multiple assignment in one statement, for example separated by comma operator, but that's apparently not what is sought here).    There's still the valid question of WHY you want to do that, since it is completely unnecessary - by DESIGN - in C++ to define any variable (or array) before it can be initialised.

Comment: @lorem1213 `{ ...some code...; std::string mystring[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"}; ...code using mystring...}` -- Code organized this way makes your question moot.  Also recommended C++ coding style is to declare variables close to where they will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `std::array<std::string, 5>` instead of the raw array.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, 5> mstring;
    
    mstring = { "veena", "guitar", "sitar", "sarod", "mandolin" };

    for ( const auto &s : mstring )
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
veena guitar sitar sarod mandolin
```

Another approach when a raw array is used is to use `std::initializer_list` in range-based for loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string mstring[5];
    
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( auto s : { "veena", "guitar", "sitar", "sarod", "mandolin" } )
    {
        mstring[i++] = s;
    }

    for ( const auto &s : mstring )
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
veena guitar sitar sarod mandolin
```

If your compiler supports C++ 20 then instead of these statements

```
size_t i = 0;

for ( auto s : { "veena", "guitar", "sitar", "sarod", "mandolin" } )
{
    mstring[i++] = s;
}
```

you can use just one range-based for loop

```
for ( size_t i = 0; auto s : { "veena", "guitar", "sitar", "sarod", "mandolin" } )
{
    mstring[i++] = s;
}
```

Comment: @AnoopRana OP can not even know about std::array. So this information is useful for him.

Comment: If so, you could've edited the dupe list instead of reopening the question. There are plenty of dupes covering how to assing to std::array or how to use std::array and their advantages over built in array.

Comment: @AnoopRana It is not interesting to me to find duplicates.

Comment: @AnoopRana It is the first time when I answer to such a question. If I will search duplicates I will forget C++ myself.:) I need a practice.:)

Comment: Well that's one way to look at it. But then no question on SO should ever be closed.

Comment: One of the reason i downvoted is because OP asks for array and not `std::array`. You've not actually answered OP's actual question which was for built in array. OP even gave an example that uses built in array and not `std::array`. You didn't even say whether it was possible or not for built in array but only provided a workaround that uses `std::array`. Read the title again, it says: *"Assigning multiple elements of array in one statement"*.

Comment: @AnoopRana He is a beginner. You should take that into account. Moreover I showed how it can be done with a raw array. This can not be done in C. You should upvote the question of the beginner.

Comment: Whether or not he is a total begginer(in C++) cannot be said with 100% certainty though looking at the comments it does seem that they're new to C++. My point is that OP is very specific in asking their question. In particular they specifically said: *" Is there a way to combine 5 statements into one."* **and you completely ignored that**.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-liner, but I think one-lining is not possible with native arrays (at least to my best knowledge).

1. Initialize a temporary array with the desired values
2. swap pointers with the original array

In that way you can use the one-line initialization for arrays, but still can manipulate the original array before setting the values.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    
  std::string mystring[5];
  std::string tmp[5] = {"veena","guitar","sitar", "sarod", "mandolin"};
  std::swap(mystring, tmp);
  for(auto& s : mystring) std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use *comma operator* to combine multiple expressions into one statement.

```cpp
mstring[0] = "veena",
mstring[1] = "guitar",
mstring[2] = "sitar",
mstring[3] = "sarod",
mstring[4] = "mandolin";
```

Comment: +1 for Best Abuse of The Rules. Now it is one statement, as required, (but unfortunately still 5 lines).

Comment: @BoP Remove the newline characters to make it single line.